# "Password can't be blank" error when seeding database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, seeding

I'm attempting to seed my database using the data that I grabbed with the `seed_dump` gem, [found here.](https://rubygems.org/gems/seed_dump)  Anyway, the seed file generated looks legit, but it seems to be falling afoul of the user model validation:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password can't be blank

To give an idea the seed looks like this:

```
User.create!([
  {email: "1234@localhost", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$5eoHh6M2q4GjGkHClO.NqebWWhS94D8rNj5Ot6CB2qrbn7IrTfkSa", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2014-12-31 22:27:09", last_sign_in_at: "2014-12-31 22:27:09", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", admin: false}
])
```

Also, I'm using the `devise` gem for users management.

Is there an elegant way to seed the user data given this filter?

Comment: why won't you just change encrypted_password to password to pass the validation?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Thanks for the response.  Very fair question; I was actually about to give that a shot.  This was more a question to see if there's an elegant way to avoid this sort of validation when seeding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
u = User.new([
  {email: "1234@localhost", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$5eoHh6M2q4GjGkHClO.NqebWWhS94D8rNj5Ot6CB2qrbn7IrTfkSa", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2014-12-31 22:27:09", last_sign_in_at: "2014-12-31 22:27:09", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", admin: false}
])
u.save!(validate: false)
```

Comment: The syntax may have changed in Rails 6. I got an error: "ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument, Array passed," when I followed this example. I removed the array brackets, so instead it was just: `u = User.new({{email: "1234@localhost", encrypted_password: "..."})`, and that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue.  The `User.new` solution did *not* work for me.

The following solution did work, from similar question on "Seeding Users with Devise" here:
[Seeding users with Devise in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418584/seeding-users-with-devise-in-ruby-on-rails)

In short, **replace** the **encrypted_password** with **password** and a *plain text* password you are comfortable using.

Example:

```
User.create!([
  {email: "1234@localhost", password: "some_password", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2014-12-31 22:27:09", last_sign_in_at: "2014-12-31 22:27:09", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", admin: false}
])
```

You can then run `rake db:seed`.  Rails will do its magic (by automatically creating the *encrypted_password* hash) for each user, and you will be able to login normally.